# rails how can you convert / to \ in a file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on selecting files to email and then passing them to the user's notes email client.

The string I want to send to the system command should be in the format of:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe"
>   Mailto:chris@mydomain.com?Subject=MailSubject?Attach=C:\test.bat

However, the code

```
 $attached_files =   $attached_files + "?Attach="+ Rails.root.to_s + "/public/images/" + document.id.to_s + "/" + document.doc_file_file_name
```

gives me forward slashes instead:

> C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/technical_library/public/images/2/High_Durability.pdf

When that is passed to system() it won't launch the notes email. I think that the problem is that the server looks for / and the windows pc looks for \

Is there any way to easily change / to \ at least for the time being for testing?

Comment: you could try `$attached_files.gsub! '/', '\'` but I thought Rails was aware of what it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 Rails.root.join("public","images", document.id, document.doc_file_file_name)
```

?